# Is there a buffer version to the EdgesGeometry (e.g. EdgesBufferGeometry) in Three.js?

Tags: javascript, web, three.js, geometry, buffer

I was wondering whether there is a buffer version of the EdgesGeometry in Three.js. Or maybe an alternative that can be used instead of EdgesGeometry.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The name might be a bit confusing but `EdgesGeometry` already outputs an instance of `BufferGeometry`. Yes, the class has an internal dependency to `Geometry` but that should not be visible for a user of the engine.

Comment: Thank you very much! That's really useful info for me